# string composition in c#

Tags: c#, .net, string, string-concatenation

I'm trying to figure out why this code doesn't work in C# and how to fix it.

```
string first = "hello";
string second = "look at" + first + "me";
```

Any suggestions?

Edit:
Sorry, I thought that the mistake I was making was a simple newbie error. I guess there's more to it.
This is my actual code:

```
 string toolOp = lstToolOpen.SelectedValue.ToString();
 string sqlComm = "INSERT INTO ES_TOOL_FACET (esfa_facet, esfa_tool) values (" +
            + toolOp + ", " +  cmbFacet.SelectedValue +"   ) ";
```

The error I get is: Operator + cannot be applied to operand of type 'string'. There's a red line under toolOp on the 3rd line of code.

Comment: What is it that doesn't work? What is the expected result?

Comment: Care to explain in what way it doesn't work and what you expect? second becomes "look athellome", maybe you should add spaces?

Comment: It looks good to me. What error give visual studio to you?

Comment: Works fine. It even compiles. Better than a lot of code I've seen posted on here.

Comment: So you just need to add a ToString() on the cmbFacet.SelectedValue :p

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have two `+` before `toolOp`. It should be:

```
string sqlComm = "INSERT INTO ES_TOOL_FACET (esfa_facet, esfa_tool) values (" +
        toolOp + ", " +  cmbFacet.SelectedValue +"   ) ";
```

This being said I would recommend you to use parametrized queries. Remember that everytime you use the `+` operator when constructing a SQL query you are doing it wrong:

```
string sqlComm = "INSERT INTO ES_TOOL_FACET (esfa_facet, esfa_tool) VALUES (@esfa_facet, @esfa_tool)";
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@esfa_facet", toolOp);
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@esfa_tool", cmbFacet.SelectedValue);
```

Now you are safe against SQL injections.

Conclusion: **never** use `+` with SQL queries.

Comment: Unless the data is coming from a trusted source.  And don't even do it then.

Comment: +1 For using a parameterized query. String Concatenation in SQL is always and without any exception wrong.

Comment: @cdhowie, even if the data comes from a trusted source you shouldn't use `+`. Even if the source is trusted the data is not properly encoded for the query. It may contain dangerous characters such as `'` or `"` which will break the query.

Comment: @Darin @cdhowie: Not never, I use `+` with SQL queries ... when I want to give an example of sql injection to others and tell them not to use this.

Comment: Have also seen `string.Format` which as evil as `+` I assume

Comment: @Andrzej Nosal, yes `string.Format` should be avoided as well.

Comment: Thanks. All the tips are much appreciated.